# Using image files on disk with R animation package

Tags: r, animation

I used R to create a series of images that took a long time to run. I'd like to use the animation package to make a video from them without re-running the analysis.

I can't find an example using existing images from file. The closest is Yihui Xie's demo('flowers') to create an HTML animation. I changed his code and can successfully make an mp4 of the flower images but I'm not sure how to access images already on file.

Based on his code, it should be something like this:

```
library(animation)
oopts = if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
ani.options(ffmpeg = "C:/Software/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-20151015-git-0418541-win64-static/bin/ffmpeg.exe")}

#My list of images from disk
extList = list.files(myDir, pattern='.jpg', full.names=T)
saveVideo({
for (i in 1:length(extList)) {

#Yihui Xie's example downloads jpegs from web
#This code works to make an mp4 but I want to use images from disk
#extList = c('http://i.imgur.com/rJ7xF.jpg',
#         'http://i.imgur.com/Lyr9o.jpg',
#          'http://i.imgur.com/18Qrb.jpg')
#download.file(url = extList[i], destfile = sprintf(ani.options('img.fmt'), i), mode = 'wb')

someFunctionToAccessImage(extList[i])

  }
}, video.name='notFlowers.mp4',
use.dev = FALSE, 
ani.type = 'jpg',
interval = 2, 
single.opts = "'dwellMultiplier': 1")
```

Bonus question - Can I do this with PNGs or other image types?

Comment: Is the deleted answer you posted not the solution?

Comment: No, Roman, it wasn't. I thought it was but then I noticed very odd behavior when running the code twice so I deleted that solution.

Answer (score 4):

I found there to be a couple of problems with this.  `saveVideo` uses a temporary directory to process the files and make the movie.  Also, the postfix it was adding to the image name wasn't working correctly.  So, here is a way to do it where you copy the images from the folder you have them stored in into the temporary directory used by `saveVideo`.  The tricky part is finding the path to that directory, which is done using `sys.frame` from a function defined in the expression.

Note: another possible option could be to manually copy the images to the temporary folder that you know `saveVideo` will use (it will call `tempdir()`), or redefine `tempdir()` to return the path to your current images, but I haven't tested that.

```
library(animation)
oopts = if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows")
    ani.options(ffmpeg = "C:\\home\\src\\ffmpeg-20151017-git-e9299df-win64-static\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe")

## Some variables
dirPath <- normalizePath("images/")  # path to folder containing images
postfix <- "%03d"                    # I created my files with "Rplot%03d"

## Make the animation
saveVideo({
    ## Need to retrieve some variables from environments up the call stack
    env.info <- (function() { list(wd = sys.frame(-1)$owd, fmt=sys.frame(-2)$img.fmt,
                                   e=sys.frame(-2)) })()
    postfix <- postfix
    img.fmt <- gsub("%d", postfix, env.info$fmt, fixed=TRUE)
    assign('img.fmt', img.fmt, envir=env.info$e)
    file.copy(list.files(dirPath, full.names = TRUE), to=env.info$wd, overwrite = TRUE)
}, video.name='heatBalls.mp4', img.name='Rplot', interval = .05, use.dev=FALSE)
```

---

#### Full example

```
## Random function to save some images to disk
circ <- function(x,y,r) { s <- seq(-pi,pi,len=30); data.frame(x=x+r*cos(s), y=y+r*sin(s)) }
imgFun <- function(n, ncircs, dirPath) {
    if (!require(scales)) stop("install scales package")
    rads <- runif(ncircs, 0.5, 3)
    xs <- runif(ncircs, 0.1+rads, 19.9-rads)
    ys <- runif(ncircs, 0.1+rads, 19.9-rads)
    vs <- matrix(runif(ncircs*2), 2)
    cols <- colorRampPalette(c('lightblue','darkblue'), alpha=0.3)(ncircs)
    png(file.path(dirPath, 'Rplot%03d.png'))
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        image(x=seq(0, 20, length=20), y=seq(0, 20, length=20),
              z=matrix(rnorm(400),20), col=heat.colors(20, alpha=0.6), xlab='', ylab='')
        for(j in 1:ncircs) polygon(x=circ(xs[j], ys[j], rads[j]), col=alpha(cols[j],0.7))
        condx <- (xs + rads) > 20 | (xs - rads) < 0
        condy <- (ys + rads) > 20 | (ys - rads) < 0
        vs[1,condx] <- -vs[1,condx]
        vs[2,condy] <- -vs[2,condy]
        xs <- xs + vs[1,]
        ys <- ys + vs[2,]
    }
    dev.off()
}

## Create some images on disk in a folder called "images"
dirPath <- normalizePath("images/")
dir.create(dirPath)
imgFun(50, 18, dirPath)
```

Then run the above code and a movie like the following should be made.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. This looks like a great solution to anyone needing to stay within the R ecosystem. While I was waiting for a response to my question I also tried Zulko's Python module MoviePy [link](https://zulko.github.io/). Overall, it was a far easier tool to get started with and the help/examples are very complete. Highly recommended!

Comment: I think you're definitely right about not staying in the R ecosystem on this one ;p, and thanks for the link.  The most straightforward thing to do would be just use `ffmpeg` directly since you already have the images made.  But, this was fun anyway.

Comment: Yes, and Zulko says as much regarding `ffmpeg` on the MoviePy GitHub page. However, Zulko has added some amazing controls to customize movies that make it worth checking out.

And regarding staying in the R ecosystem, I killed hours trying to figure out this question in R and about 15 minutes using Zulko's module.